# Selenium: Website always opens with selenium but then the site goes completely white immediately and keeps loading forever

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, loading

I try to open the following site using selenium:
https://www.honestdoor.com/

Normally this works fine with every site with the following code:
(I am currently using google-chrome version 98.0.4758 - using ChromeDriverManager for downloading the version - see below in the code)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import time

    if __name__ == '__main__':  
      ua = UserAgent()
      userAgent = ua.random
      options = Options()
      # options.add_argument('--headless')
      options.add_experimental_option ('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
      options.add_argument("start-maximized")
      options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')                               
      options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
      options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  
      options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')   
      srv=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
      driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)    
      waitWebDriver = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)         
     
    
      link = "https://www.honestdoor.com/"  
      # link = "https://www.bcassessment.ca/"  
      # driver.minimize_window()        # optional
      driver.get (link)       
      time.sleep(1000)
```

The site opens with selenium as allways but then the site goes immediately complete white and is still loading forever with the cicle going around in the top left corner (I can only kill the chrome-task in the task manager).

When I open the site in normal chrome or incognito chrome everything works fine - it seem to only crash when I open it with selenium. With other sites (like https://www.bcassessment.ca/ I have no problems at all and the open with selenium as allways)

Why is this not working for this particular website?

Comment: There are paid services that detect selenium and refuse to serve to it to stop people scraping etc. That's a reason. There are others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that super clear about the exact issue you are facing while loading the [website](https://www.honestdoor.com/). However I was able to load the website using the following code block:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
  s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
  driver.get("https://www.honestdoor.com/")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: honestdoor]

Comment: Thanks for your response - it seems that the site for whatever reason don´t like the UserAgent() - so when i delte the following lines: ua = UserAgent(), userAgent = ua.random, options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}') everything works fine
Never saw a behaviour like this on a website using UserAgent() / fake_useragent...